# Serializing Python bytestrings to JSON, preserving ordinal character values

Tags: python, json

I have some binary data produced as base-256 bytestrings in Python (2.x).  I need to read these into JavaScript, preserving the ordinal value of each byte (char) in the string.  If you'll allow me to mix languages, I want to encode a string `s` in Python such that `ord(s[i]) == s.charCodeAt(i)` after I've read it back into JavaScript.

The cleanest way to do this seems to be to serialize my Python strings to JSON.  However, `json.dump` doesn't like my bytestrings, despite fiddling with the `ensure_ascii` and `encoding` parameters.  Is there a way to encode bytestrings to Unicode strings that preserves ordinal character values?  Otherwise I think I need to encode the characters above the ASCII range into JSON-style `\u1234` escapes; but a codec like this does not seem to be among Python's `codecs`.

Is there an easy way to serialize Python bytestrings to JSON, preserving char values, or do I need to write my own encoder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to encode bytestrings
>   to Unicode strings that preserves
>   ordinal character values?

The byte `->` unicode transformation is called `decode`, not `encode`.  But yes, decoding with a codec such as `iso-8859-1` should indeed "preserve ordinal character values" as you wish.

Comment: Well I'll be; that was pretty simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Could you just use Base64? (Python `base64` module, Javascript has several implementations, one of which is [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html).)

No reason to use escaped ASCII or UTF-8 unless your data is almost all text.